# Deal with undefined arguments more elegantly

Tags: python

The accepted paradigm to deal with mutable default arguments is:

```
def func(self, a = None):
    if a is None:
        a = <some_initialisation>
    self.a = a
```

As I might have to do this for several arguments, I would need to write very similar 3 lines over and over again. I find this un-pythonically a lot of text to read for a very very standard thing to do when initialising class objects or functions.

Isn't there an elegant one-liner to replace those 3 lines dealing with the potentially undefined argument and the standard required copying to the class instance variables?

Comment: You should only use this idiom if the default value is mutable.  And you should use `a is None` instead of `a == None`.

Comment: oh, yes. Changed the question to not spread bad things...

Comment: @mgilson I did not put self, Niklas put it there.

Comment: @Niklas : Variable 'a' becomes a mutable later, but because a function and a class argument definition is executed at definition time, one should not (unless you really know what you are doing) put something mutable as argument, otherwise risking very hard to debug results. That's what Sven meant.

Comment: @NiklasB.: I think the edit reflects what I meant.  If `<some_initialisation>` resolves to, say, an integer, you'd simply use this integer instead of `None` as the default value.

Comment: @K.-Michael: I put the `self` into the function parameter list in reaction to mgilson's comment, because you seem to have forgotten it.

Comment: *Doh* 'self' is so much in my eye-blood that I overlooked that I used it in the body! Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Eh? For a function, as opposed to a method, leaving out `self` is expected/normal/proper, and nothing about the question is method-specific.

Comment: True, so because I stumbled over this while implementing __init__, I had a self.a in the body. Niklas then had the choice to either add self as argument or to remove self. from the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a "falsy" value (0, empty string, list, dict, etc.) is not a valid value for a, then you can cut down the initialization to one line:

```
a = a or <initialize_object>
```

Comment: Or in the case where `a` could also be falsy, `a = <initialization> if a is None else a` or the other way round.

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye It's new, so the problem with that is it won't run on older Python's. Keep in mind if that's a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing the same thing is as follows:

```
def func(self,**kwargs):
    self.a=kwargs.get('a',<a_initialization>)
    ...
```

This has the added bonus that the value of a passed to the function could be None and the initialization won't overwrite it.  The disadvantage is that a user using the builtin help function won't be able to tell what keywords your function is looking for unless you spell it out explicitly in the docstring.

**EDIT**

One other comment.   The user could call the above function with keywords which are not pulled out of the kwargs dictionary.  In some cases, this is good (if you want to pass the keywords to another function for instance).  In other cases, this is not what you want.  If you want to raise an error if the user provides an unknown keyword, you can do the following:

```
def func(self,**kwargs):
    self.a=kwargs.pop('a',"Default_a")
    self.b=kwargs.pop('b',"Default_b")
    if(kwargs):  
        raise  ... #some appropriate exception...possibly using kwargs.keys() to say which keywords were not appropriate for this function.
```

Comment: I like this one. You still need to store an explicit list of the arguments that must either be provided or initialized, as well as some way of handling the individual initialization values. This tends to make things less simple to read than a set of simple `if a is None: ...` code. If you have to do this for the same variables in multiple classes and functions, you might just want to put these lines in a separate function returning the variables and call it in each function/class: `a,b,c,d = InitArgs(a,b,c,d)`

Comment: The problems with this solution are that it breaks introspection, and you have to recover the usual error messages yourself.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Don't all argument-non-specific solutions do that, though? This is all with respect to the fact that we're already deviating from the explicit approach described in the OP.

Comment: With `get` you are performing `<a_initialization>` everytime the function is called regardless if it was passed in or not. This is not a big problem for an empty list, but it is a bad setup if `<a_initialization>` can be expensive.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this

```
def func(self, a=None):
    self.a = <some_initialisation> if a is None else a
```

But why the obsession with one liners? I would usually use the 3 line version even if it gets repeated all over the place because if makes your code very easy for experienced Python programmers to read

Comment: No obsession, don't worry. But reading costs time, and I find the idiom you and Niklas provided very easily readable with only one line instead of 3. I know very well, that in general Python is not about as short as possible but as readable as possible. But as this would be very very similar for each argument that is mutable, I thought this should be possible to do more efficiently. Matter of taste, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

just a little solution I came up by using an extra function, can be improved of course:

defaultargs.py:

```
    def doInit(var, default_value,condition):
        if condition:
            var = default_value
        return var

    def func(a=None, b=None, c=None):
        a =  doInit(a,5,(a is None or not isinstance(a,int)))
        b =  doInit(b,10.0,(a is None or not isinstance(a,float)))
        c =  doInit(c,"whatever",(a is None or not isinstance(c, str)))
        print a
        print b
        print c

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        func(10)
        func(None,12341.12)
        func("foo",None,"whowho")
```

output:

```
    10
    10.0
    whatever
    5
    10.0
    whatever
    5
    10.0
    whowho
```

I like your question. :)

**Edit: If you dont care about the variables type, please dont use isinstance().**

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of `isinstance` like this... It totally breaks duck typing and doesn't serve a particular purpose. Python is not a statically typed language. Also, your last code sample won't work.

Comment: I wrote " a better way of course would be...I dont know myself if this would work..." and if you really like only to have some ints or whatever isinstance is wonderful. If you dont care, then dont use it.

Comment: The point is that in Python, you *should* not care about the specific type of things. You should only care about what kinds of operations/methods something supports. Also, can you please remove the non-functioning piece of code? It's irrelevant.

Comment: Well it is possible that I use too much c++ thinking when doing python. And I removed the piece of code.